# skip characters in like clause of mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

hello I want to skip some character while matching any string using `like` using `mysql`. For example I have a string like this `2011-07-12 06:09`. I want to match the only month part of the time stamp not whole. I know I can use `%` for whole string. I want to skip characters from front and end of that part. Would any body tell me how to accomplish this job

Comment: Why not use the MONTH() MySQL function?  You're better off using date/time related functions to work with date/time datatypes than string related functions.

Comment: Why is the value stored as a string and not as a timestamp?

Comment: @Adam Bernier Thanks dude. The values is stored as time stamp not a string. Actually I want to handle a situation in which user searched `july`, I want to show the results of 07 months

Comment: In that case you'd use `select * from table where MONTH(timestamp_col) = 7`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`MONTH()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) function for grabbing the month from a date. Don't re-invent the wheel.

If you're **really** interested in matching a string using `like`, you'd be better off using the underscore (`_`) as a the wildcard:

```
select *
from some_table
where some_column like '__-07-__ __:__'
```

Comment: That would match '12-077777abcd', which is not a date.

Comment: Yeah, but he says that he is storing datetime.